# How do I solve these simultaneous equations with restrictions?

Tags: matrices

Let's say I have

$an_1+bn_2+cn_3=n_T$

$ap_1+bp_2+cp_3=p_T$

$ak_1+bk_2+ck_3=k_T$

where $a,b,c \geqslant 0$

What's the best way to find solutions for a, b and c so that the results of the sums are as close as possible to the terms on the right-hand side?
My method has been a brute-force search but maybe there's a better way.
I tagged this with 'matrices' because I didn't know what else to tag it with.

I've also thought about trying to find the variance of the variances to determine a best fit.

Comment: So the $n_i$, $p_i$ and $k_i$ are given? What do you mean by "the results of the sums are as close as possible to the terms on the right-hand sides"?

Answer (score 1):

First, rewrite the system as $Ax = d$:
$$
 \begin{pmatrix}   
     n_1 & n_2 & n_3 \\
     p_1 & p_2 & p_3 \\
     k_1 & k_2 & k_3 
   \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}   
     a \\
     b \\
     c 
   \end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}   
     n_T \\
     p_T \\
     k_T 
   \end{pmatrix}
$$
If $A$ is non-singular, i.e. $\operatorname{det}(A) \neq 0$, and $d \neq 0$, then the system has one solution, namely $$ x = A^{-1} d,$$
which might violate the condition $a,b,c \geqslant 0.$

However, if $\operatorname{det}(A) = 0$, then you are looking for a vector $x$ in the nullspace of $A$. You will have to find the *nullspace basis* of $A$: $\{ B_1, \ldots, B_{3-r} \}$, where $r = {\rm rank}(A)$. and form a vector $x = \sum B_i$ s.t. $x$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: This was a hint longer than a comment.

Comment: I know how to solve when a,b,c can be less than zero. But that's not the case.  I don't know where to start with your last paragraph. I'm not familiar enough with matrices to understand it.

Comment: I'm assuming you're given $n_i$'s, $p_i$'s, $k_i$'s and $n_T, p_T, k_T$. Then you will form to linear system above and solve by $x = A{-1} d$ which will give you a vector of three values $x=(a,b,c)$. Now, in some cases, it happens that ${\rm det}(A) = 0$ and more than one solution exists. What you do in this case, is to find what is called the homogeneous solution.

Comment: ... A simple way to do so, is to move the RHS vector to LHS and have: $$ \begin{pmatrix}   
     n_1 & n_2 & n_3 & n_T \\
     p_1 & p_2 & p_3 & p_T\\
     k_1 & k_2 & k_3 & k_T 
   \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}   
     a \\
     b \\
     c 
   \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0
   \end{pmatrix} $$ The vector $x = (a,b,c)$ you're looking for is a *nullspace* vector of the matrix above. Think of the matrix as function that maps vectors to vectors. It really scrambles the entries of the vectors. In this case, it scrambles $x$ and produces the zero vector $(0,0,0)$. Finding a nullspace..

Comment: ...basis is a standard operation in linear algebra. The basis is a general *parametric* formula for all such $x$'s. What you need to do in this case, is to search for parameters such that $x$ satisfies the conditions $a,b,c \ge 0$.

Comment: @KorganRivera sorry for delayed response. For some reason I didn't get a notification in my inbox that you made a comment.

Comment: Thanks, I can learn from that.  However, for a solution to my problem I took an easy way out and wrote a genetic algorithm to find my solution. Worked!